# how do I run torrents on android?

Tags: android, bittorrent

I am not aware of any application on android that is capable of downloading torrents. So in-case I would like to port an Ubuntu application like transmission or another similar light weight application would it be that easy. How much of socket programming would I actually require to do in such a case.

Also if anyone is aware of a project of this nature which is ongoing, I would love to have a look at it. I specifically intend to do this for android 1.6 and 1.5, so I think that makes any new API's which might have been released for this purpose pretty redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some programs exist under Androïd, but they usually only activate a remote bittorrent client from your computer for a specific file.

However I've heard of two real bittorrent clients **projects**, but didn't have a look at them :

aBTC   : http://www.androlib.com/android.application.org-ale-abtc-qmzp.aspx

Marvin : helloandroid.com/apps/marvin-bittorrent-client

Comment: Some how that link doesn't seem to open on my network!? Is it region specific?

Answer (score 1):

dTor is a fairly new but very nice torrent client for Android devices. Despite its poor reviews on the Market, I have found it to be much better than all of the competitors. The developers are very active and there has been updates to it every week for the past month which have been making it much more stable.

You can check it out here: http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-dtor-jwttw.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well, such things exist:

http://www.androlib.com/android.application.org-ale-abtc-qmzp.aspx
http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/tools/andtorrent-bittorrent-client_fywo.html

EDIT: however, they are not for free...

Comment: makes it pretty redundant, I can buy paid apps in my country :) So the best I can manage is create my own or port one using the NDK. Or is my understanding of what the NDK is for wrong?

Comment: If there are paid ones, there shouldn't reasons why you could not write/port such app.

Comment: Seems like that app only works sometimes. Also I doubt it might work exactly like a bittorrent client. for all I know it might just be tunneling the data from the a server where the torrents are getting downloaded! There is absolutely no material I can find online that would suggest otherwise, hence I decided to ask the question here.

Answer (score 0):

To download a torrent application, download utorrent from playstore and torrentsearch app. Torrent search is like a search engine for torrent and when you get the file you want after searching just click on the file and it will automatically download on your utorrent/bittorrent app. This is a substitute for searching on the web browser